# Is the definition of algebraic interior wrong?

Tags: vector-spaces, convex-analysis

From  [C. Zalinescu, Convex Analysis in General Vector Spaces, World Scientific, River Edge, NJ,
2002.], page 2.

> Suppose X is a real vector space, let $M \in X$ be a linear subspace, and let A $\subset$ X be nonempty. The algebraic interior of A with respect to M is
> $aint_{M}A:=\{a\in X: \forall x \in M,\exists \delta>0,\forall \lambda \in[0,\delta]:a+\lambda x\in A \}.$

Is this definition worng?

Becasues it seems like that the vector $x$ should be bounded or have untity norm $\|x\|=1$.

Otherwise the condition $\forall x \in M,\exists \delta>0,\forall \lambda \in[0,\delta]:a+\lambda x\in A$ would be equivalent to the $\forall x\in M ,\|x\|=1$ the line $\{a+\lambda x:\lambda \in R\}\subset A$.

Thus $A=M$.

Clearly there is something wrong?

Comment: Do the authors assume there is a norm on $X$?

Comment: yes, x is in fact a hilbert sapce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this definition is fine. How can a definition be wrong? :)

Note that $\delta$ is allowed to depend on $x$. If the norm of $x$ goes up, $\delta$ goes down.

Comment: oh! thank you, i misunderstood the logic. $\delta$ is choosen after x, and its dependent on $x$.